# Change actor color after window is rendered

Tags: python, vtk

I'm trying to change the color of one of the actors. Seems like the method `SetColor(colors.GetColor3d("Silver"))` is not working.

I'm also tried with `b.GetMapper().ScalarVisibilityOff()` but doesn´t work.

```
import vtk


colors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()


def crear_superficie(*puntos):

    points = vtk.vtkPoints()
    polygon = vtk.vtkPolygon()
    polygon.GetPointIds().SetNumberOfIds(len(puntos))
    for i, p in enumerate(puntos):
        points.InsertNextPoint(*p)
        polygon.GetPointIds().SetId(i, i)
    polygons = vtk.vtkCellArray()
    polygons.InsertNextCell(polygon)

    # Create a PolyData
    polygonPolyData = vtk.vtkPolyData()
    polygonPolyData.SetPoints(points)
    polygonPolyData.SetPolys(polygons)

    # Create a mapper and actor
    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputData(polygonPolyData)

    actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)
    actor.GetProperty().EdgeVisibilityOn()
    actor.GetProperty().SetLineWidth(2)
    actor.GetProperty().SetColor(colors.GetColor3d("Banana"))

    return actor


def main():

    a = crear_superficie((0, 0, 0), (0, 6, 0), (15, 10, 0), (30, 6, 0), (30, 0, 0))
    b = crear_superficie((0, 6, 0), (15, 10, 0), (15, 10, 60), (0, 6, 60))
   # Add the polygon to a list of polygons


    # Visualize
    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    renderWindow.SetWindowName("Polygon")
    renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
    renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

    renderer.AddActor(a)
    renderer.AddActor(b)
    renderer.SetBackground(colors.GetColor3d("Silver"))
    renderWindow.Render()
    renderWindowInteractor.Start()
    b.GetProperty().SetColor(colors.GetColor3d("Silver"))



if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

EDIT:

After call `Render` like Nico suggested I get this Warning:

```
2020-06-01 12:45:40.413 (   5.598s) [                ]     vtkOpenGLState.cxx:1380  WARN| Hardware does not support the number of textures defined.2020-06-01 12:45:40.467 (   5.652s) [                ]     vtkOpenGLState.cxx:1380  WARN| Hardware does not support the number of textures defined.2020-06-01 12:45:40.484 (   5.669s) [                ]   vtkShaderProgram.cxx:437    ERR| vtkShaderProgram (000002380CB1D770): 1: #version 150
2: #ifndef GL_ES
3: #define highp
4: #define mediump
5: #define lowp
6: #endif // GL_ES
7: #define attribute in
8: #define varying out
9:
10:
11: /*=========================================================================
12:
13:   Program:   Visualization Toolkit
14:   Module:    vtkPolyDataVS.glsl
15:
16:   Copyright (c) Ken Martin, Will Schroeder, Bill Lorensen
17:   All rights reserved.
18:   See Copyright.txt or http://www.kitware.com/Copyright.htm for details.
19: 
20:      This software is distributed WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even
21:      the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
22:      PURPOSE.  See the above copyright notice for more information.
23:
24: =========================================================================*/
25: 
26: in vec4 vertexMC;
27:
28:
29:
30: // frag position in VC
31: out vec4 vertexVCVSOutput;
32:
33: // optional normal declaration
34: //VTK::Normal::Dec
35:
36: // extra lighting parameters
37: //VTK::Light::Dec
38: 
39: // Texture coordinates
40: //VTK::TCoord::Dec
41:
42: // material property values
43: //VTK::Color::Dec
44:
45: // clipping plane vars
46: //VTK::Clip::Dec
47:
48: // camera and actor matrix values
49: uniform mat4 MCDCMatrix;
50: uniform mat4 MCVCMatrix;
51:
52: // Apple Bug
53: //VTK::PrimID::Dec
54:
55: // Value raster
56: //VTK::ValuePass::Dec
57:
58: // picking support
59: //VTK::Picking::Dec
60:
61: void main()
62: {
63:   //VTK::Color::Impl
64:
65:   //VTK::Normal::Impl
66: 
67:   //VTK::TCoord::Impl
68: 
69:   //VTK::Clip::Impl
70:
71:   //VTK::PrimID::Impl
72:
73:   vertexVCVSOutput = MCVCMatrix * vertexMC;
74:   gl_Position = MCDCMatrix * vertexMC;
75:
76:
77:   //VTK::ValuePass::Impl
78:
79:   //VTK::Light::Impl
80:
81:   //VTK::Picking::Impl
82: }

2020-06-01 12:45:41.157 (   6.341s) [                ]   vtkShaderProgram.cxx:438    ERR| vtkShaderProgram (000002380CB1D770): Could not create shader object.
```

Comment: Please copy the error text instead of screenshot : it is easier to read and people with the same problem will be able to find your post from search engine.

Comment: I changed the image for text.

Answer (score 0):

VTK works on a lazy evaluation mode to preserve performance. You should manually ask for rendering after modifications if you want to see them.

So add a `renderWindow.Render()` after the `SetColor(colors.GetColor3d("Silver"))` line

Comment: When I call the `Render`method the color doesn't change and I get this Warning...."Hardware does not support the number of textures defined."

Comment: which version of VTK ? No problem with the 9.0 here

Comment: I'm using the 9.0.0 version.

Comment: You confirm that the script you post does not generate any warning ? And adding a `renderWindow.Render()` just after the last `SetColor` give you the warning ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Right after call `Render`

Comment: I tried call render without setting the color and the issue is the same.

Comment: If it is a warning and not an error, you should have a render window. What is displayed ? Can you update your original post (vtk version, screenshot, mention to the warning ...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215115/discussion-between-nico-vuaille-and-eduardo).